# How to find out the used Key pair name via AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm aware of `get-password-data` command which can display PasswordData data like:

```
$ aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id i-0123456789
{
    "InstanceId": "i-0123456789",
    "PasswordData": "\r\nAOh...xg==\r\n",
    "Timestamp": "2018-03-27T16:52:04.000Z"
}
```

however I'd like to know which *Key pair name* was used to launch the instance, so I can pass it using `--priv-launch-key` in order to decrypt the password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a given instance, you would first use `aws ec2 describe-instances` to get the information JSON for your instance.

The information also contains the keypair name used to create that instance.

E.g. for an instance `i-0e2x8xd7xxx`  (Note: I use the awesome tool `jq` to do JSON parsing but you can use any other solution)

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-0e2x8xd7xxx | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].KeyName'
```

Output:

```
"my_key_name"
```

You can store that in a variable, say `$keypair_name` and then pass it into your `aws ec2 get-password-data` command.

You would also need to pass in the path on your machine where your keypairs are located e.g. `$keypair_path`.

For example:

```
aws ec2 get-password-data --priv-launch-key $keypair_path/$keypair_name .....
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [@Vish answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/3828/3), I've created the following shell script:

```
#/usr/bin/env bash
# Script to show password data of the EC2 instance.
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 instance_id ..."; exit; }
keyname=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].KeyName' --output text --instance-ids $1)
pemfile=$(find ~/.ssh -name "*$keyname*.pem" -print -quit)
if [ -z "$pemfile" ]; then
  aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id $1
else
  aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id $1 --priv-launch-key $pemfile
fi
```

which aims to decrypt the password based on the key pair name. By default it's looking for the PEM file in user's `~/.ssh` folder.

Usage:

```
./show_ec2_password_data.sh i-instance_id
```